# Making Possible Combinations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

I am trying to make possible combinations of `'AB'`, like:

```
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B')].
```

I'm using `itertools.permutations`, but its just returning, `[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A')]`

What would be the procedure to have both `('A','A')` and `('B','B')` too.

Also, here I am talking with input `'AB'`. What would be the procedure if I had to make combinations of input `'AB'`, `'BA'` such that the output is `[('AB','AB'), ('AB, 'BA'), ('BA', 'BA'), ('BA','BA'])`.

Also, I don't worry about the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool from itertools you are looking for is `product`.

```
>>> list(itertools.product('AB', repeat=2))
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B')]
```

This will give all possible arrangements of the specified elements that are of length 2 (specified by the `repeat` keyword).
Both `permutations` and `combinations` [explicitly state](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) that they do not repeat elements.
The function `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` is close to what you want, which allows repeated elements, but only gives distinct combinations, rather than all permutations.  The function `itertools.permutations_with_replacement` doesn't exist, because this is exactly what `itertools.product` gives you.

Comment: Thanks K. Nielson for the kind guidance.

itertools.product worked fine for the input, 'AB'

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what Nielson added, you can also obtain the required result without using `itertools`,

```
x = 'AB'
l = [(a, b) for a in x for b in x]
```

This will produce the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Pawan for the help. Yes, it works the same as itertools.